# Shoes problems: clipboard and scroll bar

Tags: scrollbar, clipboard, shoes

The code below has (at least) two problems: the `Copy` button doesn't update the clipboard, and the `edit_box` doesn't show a vertical scroll bar when it should.

```
Shoes.app (:title => "Test", :width => 1000, :height => 600) do
  background "#DFA"
  stack :margin => 30 do
    flow do
      button "Paste" do
        @sql.text = clipboard
      end
      button "Copy", :margin_left => 15 do
        clipboard = @sql.text
        alert(@sql.text.length.to_s + " characters copied to clipboard.")
      end
    end
    stack :margin_top => 10, :width => "100%", :height => 500, :scroll => true do
      @sql = edit_box :width => "100%", :height => "100%"
    end
  end
end
```

The `Paste` button correctly pastes the clipboard contents into the `edit_box`.  If you make changes, then click `Copy`, the `alert` message displays the correct number of characters.  If you then click `Paste` again, the original clipboard contents are pasted.  The `Copy` button never correctly updates the clipboard.

Also, if you generate more lines than fit the `edit_box`, either by editing or pasting, no scroll bar ever appears.

Any help on these two issues will be much appreciated.  My environment is Windows XP if that helps.

**UPDATE WITH ANSWERS:** Thanks to @Pesto for answering the clipboard question.  It turns out that qualifying `clipboard` with either `app.` or `self.` works as expected in both the `Paste` and `Copy` buttons.

After digging deeper into the scrollbar issue, I think I understand why the `edit_box` doesn't show a scrollbar.  The scrollbar in Shoes applies only to slots (`stack` and `flow`), and not to individual elements like `edit_box`.  The `edit_box` height is specified in such a way as to always fit within the enclosing `stack`, so the `stack` never needs a scrollbar.  This led me to a work-around that is not ideal, but is acceptable for my application.  Simply change the `edit_box` height to a larger-than-necessary value such as `"10000px"` and the scrollbar appears.  Unfortunately, it's there whether needed or not, but that's better than no scrollbar.  I'm sure that some additional tinkering can dynamically change the `edit_box` height to exactly fit the contents, so that the scrollbar will appear only when needed.

Comment: Having read your update, I'd say that this is probably fine as a temporary fix, but don't think you'll be stuck with it.  The lack of scrollbars is a bug that apparently only affects Windows.  The next couple releases should contain significant effort in improving Windows and OSX, and hopefully this will be among the fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the easy one: change the line in the Copy button to `app.clipboard = @sql.text`.

Second, as far as the scrollbar goes, this is a [known issue](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.shoes/2304) on Windows XP.  I don't see it listed in the bug reports on github, but the latest version (r1229) still doesn't have a scrollbar.

Comment: Many thanks. The app.clipboard fix works perfectly. Why is this not required in the Paste function?

Comment: For the simple reason that without using "app", the interpreter doesn't know that you're looking for the clipboard= method instead of just assigning a local variable named clipboard.  It's not a shoes thing, it's a Ruby thing.