# Shoes Clipboard Access from App

Tags: ruby, shoes

I am having problems getting the clipboard contents from within an app, using ruby shoes.
I have tried the solution [Shoes problems: clipboard and scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798947/shoes-problems-clipboard-and-scroll-bar), which does not work, as well as several other self-made solutions. According to http://shoesrb.com/manual/App.html, these attempts should work. My current attempt is:

```
def someFunction
    @theapp = Shoes.app(title: "AppName", width: 400) {
        @clip = edit_box width: 400, height: 400, text: app.clipboard do
            app.clipboard = @clip.text
        end
    }
end
```

As well as referencing app.clipboard, I have attempted `Shoes.clipboard`, `Shoes.app.clipboard`,  `self.clipboard`, and `@theapp.clipboard`, all of which have failed. Some of them have even caused a blank window to appear without any elements in it. How can I fix this strange issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try capturing the content of the edit_box in a block parameter:

```
Shoes.app do
  edit_box do |clip|
    app.clipboard = clip.text
  end
end
```

Your question helped us to [fix a bug](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/pull/1010) in the upcoming release of Shoes 4. Thanks :)